# Set focus in a textbox

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, setfocus

When I type in `SetFocus` it is ignored.

```vb
If IsNull(Me.txtStaffID) Or IsNull(Me.txtPassword) Then
    MsgBox "You have not entered your Staff ID please do so"
    Me.txtStaffID.BackColor = vbRed
    Me.txtStaffID.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
 
ElseIf IsNull(Me.txtPassword) Then
    MsgBox "You have not entered your Password please do so"
    Me.txtPassword.BackColor = vbRed
    Me.txtPassword.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
```

Comment: *when I type in Setfocus it is ignored* What does this words mean? Access removes this word?

Comment: PS. AS I understand `txtStaffID` and `txtPassword` are textboxes on the form. If so they will never be NULL. You must check does `Me.txtTextBox.Text = ""`. Or maybe trim additionally - user may enter a lot of spaces...

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is incomplete. Try:

```vb
If IsNull(Me.txtStaffID) Then    
    MsgBox "You have not entered your Staff ID, please do so."
    Me.txtStaffID.BackColor = vbRed
    Me.txtStaffID.SetFocus
ElseIf IsNull(Me.txtPassword) Then
    MsgBox "You have not entered your Password, please do so."
    Me.txtPassword.BackColor = vbRed
    Me.txtPassword.SetFocus
End If
```